# Google Place Details does not return photos array

Tags: google-maps, http, ionic3, google-places-api

I am sorry if this question has an answer somewhere, I have searched and did not find any answer and I don't know what to do anymore.

I am developing an Ionic3 application and I am trying to search for a place on Google maps and then retrieve photos related to that place using Google Place details API. But photos are not returned. I have tried multiple combinations, even tried other places. Some other fields are returned but just not photos.

This is how I tried to retrieve :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=photo,name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and I tried getting details via :

```
http.get(" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=photo,name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY")
.subscribe((data)=>{
   console.log(data)
   });
```

I replaced the place id and API KEY with mine. But no photo is returned.

Some of the fields inputted are returned but not photos.

What is the best way to retrieve photos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel this might be relevant for someone in this situation too. Going through the documentation again, I realized that Places API does not return photos for other **types** other than the following types: **establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest**. Most of my place search types were routes so it didn't return photos. But when the types were changed to match the allowed ones, photos were returned.

For example, Places does not return photos of a particular street except if it is a prominent point of interest as indicated above.

To get photos of street, Street View API might be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

in `Place Details API` (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) will result you will get `photo_reference` and inside you will find `photos[]` array

Now the *place photo* service is apart of the places API
then use **Place Photo Requests** to get the photo.

have a look in below url for service call

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=PHOTO_REFERENCE&sensor=false&maxheight=MAX_HEIGHT&maxwidth=MAX_WIDTH&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Refrence: (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)